# I cant traduce this chunk of GAS code to INTEL/NASM syntax

Tags: assembly, syntax, macros, c-preprocessor, gnu-assembler

in this code:

```
#define G(gi1, gi2, x, t0, t1, t2, t3) \
lookup_32bit(t0, t1, t2, t3, ##gi1, RGS1, shr_next, ##gi1);  \
lookup_32bit(t0, t1, t2, t3, ##gi2, RGS3, shr_next, ##gi2);  \
\
lookup_32bit(t0, t1, t2, t3, ##gi1, RGS2, dummy, none);      \
shlq $32,   RGS2;                                        \
orq     RGS1, RGS2;                                  \
lookup_32bit(t0, t1, t2, t3, ##gi2, RGS1, dummy, none);      \
shlq $32,   RGS1;                                        \
orq     RGS1, RGS3;

#define lookup_32bit(t0, t1, t2, t3, src, dst, interleave_op, il_reg) \
movzbl      src ## bl,        RID1d;     \
movzbl      src ## bh,        RID2d;     \
shrq $16,   src;                         \
movl        t0(CTX, RID1, 4), dst ## d;  \
movl        t1(CTX, RID2, 4), RID2d;     \
movzbl      src ## bl,        RID1d;     \
xorl        RID2d,            dst ## d;  \
movzbl      src ## bh,        RID2d;     \
interleave_op(il_reg);               \
xorl        t2(CTX, RID1, 4), dst ## d;  \
xorl        t3(CTX, RID2, 4), dst ## d;
```

"gi1" becomes RDX, in the beginning, but furthermore I can't translate it regard of its usage in the "movzbl" instruction. Basically I can't figure out the movzbl ??? ???, RID1d
I am NASM user

full code here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/crypto/twofish-avx-x86_64-asm_64.S

Comment: The hard part of this for me is the use of the token-pasting operator `##` with nothing to the left of it but a comma. I don't know what that does. I'm tagging the question with c-preprocessor to see if that gets the attention of someone who understands it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still slightly confused by the uses of `##` in `G`. I found a [section of the GNU cpp manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html#Variadic-Macros) which mentions `##` after a comma, but it's meant for use in variadic macros, and this isn't one of those.

But I'm going ahead with an explanation anyway, based on the assumption that those `##` are not doing anything.

The `##` in  `lookup_32bit`, on the other hand, are perfectly normal and necessary.

Let's go up a level from the `G` macro and see how it's called. One of its calls looksl ike this:

```
G(RGI1, RGI2, x1, s0, s1, s2, s3)
```

Its first argument, `RGI1`, becomes `gi1` in the expansion. The first piece of the `G` macro:

```
lookup_32bit(t0, t1, t2, t3, ##gi1, RGS1, shr_next, ##gi1)
```

expands `lookup_32bit` with `##gi1` as the 5th and 8th arguments. I'm assuming `##gi1` works the same as `gi1`, so the 5th and 8th arguments will be `RGI1`.

Inside the `lookup_32bit` macro, the 5th and 8th arguments are called `src` and `il_reg`, so both of those will expand to `RGI1` in this instance. The first instruction in `lookup_32bit`:

```
movzbl      src ## bl,        RID1d;
```

pastes the `src` argument (`RGI1`) together with `bl` (which is not a macro or a macro argument, so it just represents itself), resulting in the pasted token `RGI1bl`. The instruction now looks like this:

```
movzbl      RGI1bl,        RID1d;
```

After the first pass of expanding `lookup_32bit` is done, the preprocessor will look again for macros to expand, and `RGI1bl` is a macro defined like this:

```
#define RGI1bl %dl
```

Also, `RID1d` is a macro defined like this:

```
#define RID1d %ebp
```

so the instruction ends up being:

```
movzbl      %dl,        %ebp;
```

and that's just a zero-extending move from 8-bit register `%dl` to 32-bit register `%ebp.

Looking at the other macros, you can see that there are a bunch of them starting with `RGI1` all of which resolve to `%rdx` or portions of it. With these macros in place, selecting the low 8-bit portion of a 64-bit register can be done by pasting `bl` onto the end with `##`, which wouldn't be possible using the native register names directly (there's no preprocessor operation as sophisticated as "remove the `r` from the front of this token and change the final `x` to an `l`).

The specific names `RGI1`, `RID1`, etc. don't look familiar to me. I'll guess they are derived from the twofish specification.

Token-pasting reference: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation

Comment: People in this place don't make me feel stupid because I'm asking something I don't know!
I'm not trying to use the code from that page. I just try to understand the Twofish algorithm. Thank you again!